# Some journalctl ERRORS

Tags: kernel, systemd, acpi, dbus, wpa-supplicant

I've been having some error shown on `journalctl -b -p err` command output, could you guys shed some light on how I could solve them and explain the reason behind them?

[image: journalctl -b -p err output]

For those who can't load the picture, it's

```
kernel: ACPI Error: No handler for Region [EC__] (        (ptrval)) [EmbeddedControl] (20170831/evregion-166)
kernel: ACPI Error: Region EmbeddedControl (ID=3) has no handler (20170831/exfldio-299)
kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._REG, AE_NOT_EXIST (20170831/psparse-550) # same three lines twice
kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
kernel: PKCS#7 Signature not signed with a trusted key # x3
kernel: ACPI Error: [\_SB.PCI0.GFX0.DD02._BCL] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)
kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.DD02._BCL, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)
kernel: PKCS#7 Signature not signed with a trusted key
```

followed by `bluetoothd`, `systemd`, `spice-vdagent`, `pulseaudio`, and `wpa_supplicant` taking turns to complain. Not sure if the sequence matters.

I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: The picture you provide is of (red!) text, please just copy/paste text into your question as it's much easier to read, plus we can copy/paste it in replies to you.

Comment: You can eliminate the PCKS #7 errors by disabling secure boot in your BIOS

Comment: If disabling `secure boot` doesn't fix the PKCS#7 error, you'll have to look in `/var/log/syslog` to see if it calls out the driver that's throwing this error. Also, in `terminal` type `rfkill` and make sure that nothing is blocked. The other errors are mostly noise. Are you having a specific problem that we can help you with?

Comment: @CharlesGreen please see my comment. Secure Boot may not fix the PKCS#7 error...

Comment: @guiverc Sorry, newbie here.

Comment: @heynnema I ain't having any major problems, just being a 
little perfectionist and trying to learn more in the process. Hehe

Comment: Gonna test your solutions, I'll give you a feedback later, thanks people.

Comment: I've unblocked the bluetooth software using the `rfkill unblock ID` command and it worked. As for the PKCS#7 errors, this is the output of the command `grep PKCS#7 /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: Just looking at `err` messages can give one an incomplete picture. Try `-p warning`, `-p notice` or `-p info` to get more information from the surrounding messages.

Answer (score 0):

`grep PKCS#7 /var/log/syslog`

```
Feb  6 01:12:06 yuri-GE60-2QD kernel: [    1.385519] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Feb  6 01:12:06 yuri-GE60-2QD kernel: [    1.403128] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Feb  6 01:12:06 yuri-GE60-2QD kernel: [    1.404485] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Feb  6 01:12:06 yuri-GE60-2QD kernel: [   34.213590] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Feb  6 08:50:24 yuri-GE60-2QD kernel: [    1.116140] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Feb  6 08:50:24 yuri-GE60-2QD kernel: [    1.142025] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Feb  6 08:50:24 yuri-GE60-2QD kernel: [    1.143222] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
Feb  6 08:50:24 yuri-GE60-2QD kernel: [   33.747217] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
```

Comment: Hi! - please place additional data such as this, into your question rather than an answer.